# Cannot import Elastic Search: Unknown Location

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search

I am new to elastic search and I am trying to import it into one of my python projects. I keep getting the following error:

```
File "./test1.py", line 3 , in <module>
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: cannot import name 'Elasticsearch' from 'elasticsearch' (unknown location)
```

I already have elastic search 6.4 installed (I ran `pip install elastic search` and it did install) and I have my bash profile set to `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. Elastic search is installed, but it can't be found. The code below is what I am trying to run on a Mac terminal.

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

Comment: Try creating a new virtual environment and make a fresh install. It will work

Answer (score 0):

well, in your place, I would double check if I am using the same virtual environment (if any) and make sure that `elasticsearch` is recognized by the python interpreter:

- from inside the virtual env:

```sh
python -m pip show elasticsearch
```

- inside a python script:

```py
try:
 import elasticsearch
except ImportError, e:
 print('elasticsearch is not installed')
```

and to double check, I tested:

```sh
python -m pip install elasticsearch
```

then in a `test1.py`:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
print(Elasticsearch())
```

I got:

```sh
<Elasticsearch([{}])>
```

The full documentations can be found here: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

hope this helps you find your way.